# How to copy and manipulate dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to manipulate a dictionary for a couple of textures that I'm working on. I'm able to generate this using a script that I made.

```
{
   "texture": {
      "asset": "monster", 
      "element": "damaged", 
      "job": "test", 
      "maps": {
         "files": [
            {
               "file": "monster/damaged/hi/bump/bump.1001.tif", 
               "md5sum": "5ff5779466612a3ec447c4d0ddc99e48"
            }, 
            {
               "file": "monster/damaged/hi/matte/matteSleeve.1002.tif", 
               "md5sum": "f383ceb943671d1bf6ac8dcfbe640fa1"
            }
         ], 
         "version": "1"
      }, 
      "resolution": "hi", 
      "when": "11:20PM"
   }
}
```

What I want to do next is to copy the `files` and `version` and create a version 2 of those.

```
{
   "texture": {
      "asset": "monster", 
      "element": "damaged", 
      "job": "test", 
      "maps": [
          {
             "files": [
                {
                   "file": "monster/damaged/hi/bump/bump.1001.tif", 
                   "md5sum": "5ff5779466612a3ec447c4d0ddc99e48"
                }, 
                {
                   "file": "monster/damaged/hi/matte/matteSleeve.1002.tif", 
                   "md5sum": "f383ceb943671d1bf6ac8dcfbe640fa1"
                }
             ], 
             "version": "1"
          },
          {
             "files": [
                {
                   "file": "monster/damaged/hi/bump/bump.1001.tif", 
                   "md5sum": "5ff5779466612a3ec447c4d0ddc99e48"
                }, 
                {
                   "file": "monster/damaged/hi/matte/matteSleeve.1002.tif", 
                   "md5sum": "sfh4eb94367145fd6ac8dcfbe640fa1"
                }
             ], 
             "version": "2"
          }
      ],
      "resolution": "hi", 
      "when": "11:20PM"
   }
}
```

How do copy or duplicate this using Python? If you could point some documentation for this, that would be great as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [deepcopy](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-copy-a-dictionary-shallow-copy-vs-deep-copy/).

```py
import copy
dict['texture']['maps'].append(copy.deepcopy(dict['texture']['maps'][0]))
```

By using a deep copy, you avoid the problem of the new dictionary still holding references to the old one.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I did an update afterwards to change the version number. Not sure its the most efficient way to do it, but it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
d1 = {"x": 1}
d2 = d1.copy()
d1["x"] = 2
print("d1 :", d1)
print("d2 :", d2)
```

Output :

```
d1 : {'x': 2}
d2 : {'x': 1}
```

More info [here](https://www.science-emergence.com/Articles/How-to-copy-a-dictionary-in-python-/)

Comment: This is a shallow copy, the new dict will change if the old one is. Also, your example never sets `d2['x']` to 1, so this is incorrect

Comment: Hmm you're right, it only works with a depth = 1, but not with dicts contained in dicts. I also changed the initiation with `d1 = {"x": 1}`, so my example is correct now, thx for noticing it.